# Modify checkbox font when ticked using vba

Tags: vba

I have a document with several Y/N checkboxes.  Certain areas of the document, when Y is checked, I want the checkbox font to change colors and bold.  Other areas I want this to happen when N is checked.

The problems I'm having are

- I can't figure out how to make font bold, I just can do the color change.
- When the user clicks any of the checkboxes, a dialog window pops up saying "UpdateForm"
  The user must click "OK".
  Then another one pops up that says "UpdateForm" and "Finished".
  Again the user must click "OK".

Here is my code:

```
Public Sub UpdateForm()
    On Error GoTo ERRUpdateForm
    Dim FF As Long
    Dim BM As Long
    Dim strFF As String
    Dim BolCheck As Boolean

    Dim ctl As FormField
    MsgBox "UpdateForm"
    ActiveDocument.Unprotect "password"

    For FF = 1 To ActiveDocument.FormFields.Count
        strFF = ActiveDocument.FormFields(FF).Name
            BolCheck = ActiveDocument.FormFields(FF).CheckBox.Value

            Select Case strFF
                'Page 2
                Case "Check01Y"
                    If BolCheck Then
                        ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("Check01Txt").Range.Font.Color = RGB(102, 153, 0)
                    Else
                        ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("Check01Txt").Range.Font.Color = RGB(0, 0, 0)
                    End If
                Case "Check02Y"
                    If BolCheck Then
                        ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("Check02Txt").Range.Font.Color = RGB(102, 153, 0)
                    Else
                        ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("Check02Txt").Range.Font.Color = RGB(0, 0, 0)
                    End If
                Case "Check03Y"
                    If BolCheck Then
                        ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("Check03Txt").Range.Font.Color = RGB(102, 153, 0)
                    Else
                        ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("Check03Txt").Range.Font.Color = RGB(0, 0, 0)
                    End If
                Case "Check04Y"
                    If BolCheck Then
                        ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("Check04Txt").Range.Font.Color = RGB(102, 153, 0)
                    Else
                        ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("Check04Txt").Range.Font.Color = RGB(0, 0, 0)
                    End If
                'Rest of document
                Case "Check05N"
                    If BolCheck Then
                        ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("Check05NTxt").Range.Font.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0)
                    Else
                        ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("Check05NTxt").Range.Font.Color = RGB(0, 0, 0)
                    End If
                Case "Check06N"
                    If BolCheck Then
                        ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("Check06NTxt").Range.Font.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0)
                    Else
                        ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("Check06NTxt").Range.Font.Color = RGB(0, 0, 0)
                    End If
                Case "Check07N"
                    If BolCheck Then
                        ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("Check07NTxt").Range.Font.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0)
                    Else
                        ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("Check07NTxt").Range.Font.Color = RGB(0, 0, 0)
                    End If
                Case "Check08N"
                    If BolCheck Then
                        ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("Check08NTxt").Range.Font.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0)
                    Else
                        ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("Check08NTxt").Range.Font.Color = RGB(0, 0, 0)
                    End If
                Case "Check09N"
                    If BolCheck Then
                        ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("Check09NTxt").Range.Font.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0)
                    Else
                        ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("Check09NTxt").Range.Font.Color = RGB(0, 0, 0)
                    End If
                Case "Check10N"
                    If BolCheck Then
                        ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("Check10NTxt").Range.Font.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0)
                    Else
                        ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("Check10NTxt").Range.Font.Color = RGB(0, 0, 0)
                    End If
                Case "Check11N"
                    If BolCheck Then
                        ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("Check11NTxt").Range.Font.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0)
                    Else
                        ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("Check11NTxt").Range.Font.Color = RGB(0, 0, 0)
                    End If
                Case "Check12N"
                    If BolCheck Then
                        ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("Check12NTxt").Range.Font.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0)
                    Else
                        ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("Check12NTxt").Range.Font.Color = RGB(0, 0, 0)
                    End If
                Case "Check13N"
                    If BolCheck Then
                        ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("Check13NTxt").Range.Font.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0)
                    Else
                        ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("Check13NTxt").Range.Font.Color = RGB(0, 0, 0)
                    End If
                Case "Check14N"
                    If BolCheck Then
                        ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("Check14NTxt").Range.Font.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0)
                    Else
                        ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("Check14NTxt").Range.Font.Color = RGB(0, 0, 0)
                    End If
                Case "Check15N"
                    If BolCheck Then
                        ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("Check15NTxt").Range.Font.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0)
                    Else
                        ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("Check15NTxt").Range.Font.Color = RGB(0, 0, 0)
                    End If
                Case "Check16N"
                    If BolCheck Then
                        ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("Check16NTxt").Range.Font.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0)
                    Else
                        ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("Check16NTxt").Range.Font.Color = RGB(0, 0, 0)
                    End If
                Case "Check17N"
                    If BolCheck Then
                        ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("Check17NTxt").Range.Font.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0)
                    Else
                        ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("Check17NTxt").Range.Font.Color = RGB(0, 0, 0)
                    End If
                Case "Check18N"
                    If BolCheck Then
                        ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("Check18NTxt").Range.Font.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0)
                    Else
                        ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("Check18NTxt").Range.Font.Color = RGB(0, 0, 0)
                    End If
                Case "Check19N"
                    If BolCheck Then
                        ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("Check19NTxt").Range.Font.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0)
                    Else
                        ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("Check19NTxt").Range.Font.Color = RGB(0, 0, 0)
                    End If
                Case "Check20N"
                    If BolCheck Then
                        ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("Check20NTxt").Range.Font.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0)
                    Else
                        ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("Check20NTxt").Range.Font.Color = RGB(0, 0, 0)
                    End If
                Case "Check21N"
                    If BolCheck Then
                        ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("Check21NTxt").Range.Font.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0)
                    Else
                        ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("Check21NTxt").Range.Font.Color = RGB(0, 0, 0)
                    End If
                Case "Check22N"
                    If BolCheck Then
                        ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("Check22NTxt").Range.Font.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0)
                    Else
                        ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("Check22NTxt").Range.Font.Color = RGB(0, 0, 0)
                    End If
            End Select
    Next FF

    If ActiveDocument.ProtectionType = wdNoProtection Then
        ActiveDocument.Protect _
        Type:=wdAllowOnlyFormFields, NoReset:=True, Password:="password"
    End If

    MsgBox "Finished", vbOKOnly, "Update Form"
    Exit Sub
ERRUpdateForm:
    Debug.Print "UpdateForm," & Err.Number & ","; Err.Description
    Resume Next
End Sub

Sub ResetForm()
    On Error GoTo ERRResetForm

    ActiveDocument.Unprotect "password"

    Dim BM As Bookmark
    For Each BM In ActiveDocument.Bookmarks
        If UCase(Right(BM.Name, 3)) = "TXT" Then
        BM.Range.Font.Color = RGB(0, 0, 0)
        End If
    Next BM

    If ActiveDocument.ProtectionType = wdNoProtection Then
        ActiveDocument.Protect _
        Type:=wdAllowOnlyFormFields, NoReset:=False, Password:="password"
    End If

    MsgBox "Finished", vbOKOnly, "Reset Form"
    Exit Sub
ERRResetForm:
    Debug.Print "ResetForm," & Err.Number & ","; Err.Description
    Resume Next
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to get rid of message boxes remove those lines:

```
MsgBox "Finished", vbOKOnly, "Update Form"

MsgBox "Finished", vbOKOnly, "Reset Form"

MsgBox "UpdateForm"
```

---

In order to make bold font use:

```
ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("Check01Txt").Range.Font.Bold = True
```

Comment: @ mielk - Thank you for your help, but now I'm getting a Compile Error, "Invalid or unqualified reference"  This is how I have it:
                        ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("Check01Txt").Range.Font.Color = RGB(102, 153, 0)
.Font.Bold = True
Else
                        ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("Check01Txt").Range.Font.Color = RGB(0, 0, 0)
End If

Is that right, with the "Font.Bold = True" being on the line below?